# deplyment problem in github pages react app

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

```
PS C:\Users\Panch\OneDrive\Desktop\Yourself2> npm run deploy
npm ERR! Missing script: "deploy"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Panch\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-15T16_47_39_705Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\Panch\OneDrive\Desktop\Yourself2>
```

All the possible way

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have the task defined in `package.json` (check it yourself). As you are using React, make sure `gh-pages` npm package is installed

```
npm install gh-pages --save-dev
```

In addition, you'll need to define the task under the `scripts` object located in the file `package.json`:

```
   "predeploy": "npm run build",
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
```

For instance, one of my github page react apps have the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Follow the instructions to get a more detailed answer: https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages